# Read CSV files in Java using Apache Commons CSV for loop starting index 1

Tags: java, csv, apache-poi

I have the following Code about iterating over a list of elements in a CSV file.

```
 for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
    // Accessing Values by Column Index
    String name = csvRecord.get(0);

    dates_csv.add(name);
  }

}
```

How can I start the iteration starting from Index 1 in this for loop.
I am still new to java :)

Comment: Use a regular index-based for loop instead of the current foreach one you're using?

Comment: Thank you! How to write it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
boolean firstRound = true;
for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
    if(firstRound){
        firstRound = false;
    } else {
        String name = csvRecord.get(0);
        dates_csv.add(name);
    }
}
```

or

```
List<CSVRecord> recList = csvParser.getRecords();
for(int i = 1; i < recList.size(); i++){
    dates_csv.add(recList.get(i).get(0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<CSVRecord> parserList = parser.getRecords();
for (CSVRecord csvRecord : parserList.subList(1, parserList.size()))
{ 
    //code here
}
```

Comment: How will you get `subList` from an `Iterable`?

Comment: List<CSVRecord> parserList = parser.getRecords();

Comment: for (CSVRecord csvRecord : parserList.subList(1, parserList.size())) {
    //code here 
  }
}